# Why do I get so many empty partitions when repartionning a Spark Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

I want to partition a dataframe "df1" on 3 columns. This dataframe has exactly 990 unique combinaisons for those 3 columns:

```
In [17]: df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1_view")

In [18]: spark.sql("select count(*) from (select distinct(col1,col2,col3) from df1_view) as t").show()
+--------+                                                                      
|count(1)|
+--------+
|     990|
+--------+
```

In order to optimize the processing of this dataframe, I want to partition df1 in order to get 990 partitions, one for each key possibility:

```
In [19]: df1.rdd.getNumPartitions()
Out[19]: 24

In [20]: df2 = df1.repartition(990, "col1", "col2", "col3")

In [21]: df2.rdd.getNumPartitions()
Out[21]: 990
```

I wrote a simple way to count rows in each partition:

```
In [22]: def f(iterator):
    ...:     a = 0
    ...:     for partition in iterator:
    ...:         a = a + 1
    ...:     print(a)
    ...: 

In [23]: df2.foreachPartition(f)
```

And I notice that what I get in fact is 628 partitions with one or more key values, and 362 empty partitions.

I assumed spark would repartition in an even way (1 key value = 1 partition) but that does not seem like it, and I feel like this repartitionning is adding data skew even though it should be the other way around...

What's the algorithm Spark uses to partition a dataframe on columns ?
Is there a way to achieve what I thought was possible ?

I'm using Spark 2.2.0 on Cloudera.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To distribute data across partitions spark needs somehow to convert value of the column to index of the partition. There are two default partitioners in Spark - HashPartitioner and RangePartitioner. Different transformations in Spark can apply different partitioners - e.g. `join` will apply hash partitioner.

Basically for hash partitioner formula to convert value to partition index would be `value.hashCode() % numOfPartitions`. In your case multiple values are mapping to same partition index.

You could implement your own partitioner if you want better distribution. More about it is [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-rdd-partitions.html) and [here](https://medium.com/parrot-prediction/partitioning-in-apache-spark-8134ad840b0) and [here](https://hackernoon.com/managing-spark-partitions-with-coalesce-and-repartition-4050c57ad5c4).

Comment: I succeeded in implementing a custom partitionner using [this resource](http://sparkdatasourceapi.blogspot.com/2016/10/patitioning-in-spark-writing-custom.html)
However it seems that working on the RDD API when the data is originally in a dataframe has a huge "conversion" cost...
Since I can't create a CustomPartitioner using the dataframe API, it seems that I'm stuck with the HashPartitioner and that my best course of action is to reduce the number of partitions to get an "even" distribution.

Comment: @tomcat changing partitions in RDD should not be an issue for Dataframes. Please correct me if my statements are wrong. [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html) all dataframes are just high level api for rdds. can you add resources where it says there is a conversion cost ?